# Error in Upgrading ST-link V3 to J-Link

Tags: stm32, embedded, debugging, st-link

I am getting the following error from the **STLinkReglasher** program while converting the standalone ST-Link V3 debugger into J-Link.

**ERROR: Cannot find an ST-LINK, multiple ST-LINKs plugged in, or ST-LINK is in use**

What could be wrong here. I have upgraded the firmware and have followed [this](https://mhhauto.com/Thread-Flash-ST-Link-Clone-to-J-link-STlink-Jlink)  and [this](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2020/10/12/solution-for-cannot-find-an-st-link-when-using-stlinkreflash-for-j-link-ob-conversion/) which mentioned the same issue but no success.
I can see there are numerous methods for converting on-board ST-link V2 debuggers into J-link but I am explicitly looking for V3 model. Any guidance on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried unplugging/plugging in? Have you tried to restart PC? (this will make sure any program using it will disconnect itself from it)

Comment: Yes, I have. I have another STlink v2 version. V2 version works all the time, but when I plug-in the v3 model, it gives the above mentioned error.

Comment: How do you even know that it is possible to program firmware meant for V2 also to V3, what if they are completely different devices?

Comment: sorry I am late to the party, but that is probably not possible.
https://forum.segger.com/index.php/Thread/6397-SOLVED-STLink-conversion-utility-for-STLink-v3/?postID=23614#post23614